# Espresso check all in list

Tags: android, android-espresso

Is there any ability in `espresso` to check all views in `listview`, not for get one from this, but for check all for some condition.

It seems that `onData()` serves to return interaction with only one list item from list. And it is not for my issue.

**Edit:**
Actually I have found one solution, that solves my issue, but it rather looks like spike instead of good one. 
I start StealCount action to get items count from `ListView` cuz we can not do it strait from test (cuz we are inside Inst thread). Afterwards I start check data for any items from list view using `DataInteraction`. It seems like this:

```
public static void assertAllItems(
    final Matcher<View> adapterViewMatcher, 
    final Matcher<View> itemsMatcher
) {
    StealCountAction stealCountAction = new StealCountAction();
    onView(adapterViewMatcher).perform(stealCountAction);

    DataInteraction dataInteraction = onData(anything())
        .inAdapterView(adapterViewMatcher);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < stealCountAction.count; i++) {
        dataInteraction.atPosition(i)
            .onChildView(itemsMatcher)
            .check(ViewAssertions.matches(isDisplayed()));
    }
}

static class StealCountAction implements ViewAction {

    public int count;

    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return instanceOf(AdapterView.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return "Steal count action";
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        count = ((AdapterView) view).getCount();
    }
}
```

But anyway it seems ugly for me.
Is there any other abilities?

Answer (score 1):

I would have done it in a different way.

To check a listview you only need to do something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    onData(anything())
            .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.listViewId)).atPosition(i)
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

And, previously, to get the numItems variable you need just to access to your list adapter through your ActivityTestRule:

```
 int numItems = ((ListView) mActivityRule.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listViewId)).getAdapter().getCount();
```

Or, if its inside a fragment:

```
int numItems = ((ListView) mActivityRule.getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentId).getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewId)).getAdapter().getCount();
```

Even though I understand your code I think this one is easier to be understood.
The only confusing part is the way to access to the adapter. But you can create other intermediate variables to make it more readable or create a function to get this number if you like.

Comment: In this case I suppose you do not wait any idling resources to be in idling state, cuz u just get items count from test runner thread

Comment: Well, I didn't think about this. So you mean that by getting the count/numItems from a ViewAction espresso will run your test commands at the appropriate time and this way it will not? That's a good point, I have to check this.

Comment: Yep, I suppose that if you just get Activitity from rule and get count of items straight from list, it will be done not inside main thread of you app, so it can lead to some misbehavior in tests.